# Entity Framework Connections are not getting closed.Any Automatic way to close SQL Connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5, ado.net-entity-data-model

Currently I'm using UOW to open  connection to DB and getting results. Im not sure why SQL Connections are not getting Closed. Looks like there are some open connection opened and not getting closed. I have also increased MAxPoolSize to 250

;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=250;

Is there any attribute like ConnectionLife where it auomatically closes SQL connection incase of any exceeding the time. I need help on this.

Please let me know automatically closing of connection after one minute

Comment: are you using `using` statements?

Comment: Please post your connection string. Are you disposing your dbcontext's? How are you committing your UOW?

Comment: in your context constructor: ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;   Change 180 to what ever you want

Comment: Im not disposing UOW. As i havent UOW<DBContext> has Dependency object for my controller and Service layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ended up in writing dispose method to dispose the Unit Of work Context created after each and every call to server

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MVC, Are you using entity framework objects as viewmodels in your views?

For arrays or lists try to use .ToList()

For objects try to use ViewModels and not use the object it self.